# nested dictionary --> dataframe with multi - columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

```
kdict = {'A': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 'B': {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, 'C': {'a': 5, 'b': 6}}

df5 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(kdict, orient='index').stack()
df5.columns = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
print(df5)
```

[image]

but i want to get the result, as below --

[image]

how can i get this form, as above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to convert the Series to DataFrame and transpose:

```py
print(df5.to_frame().T)
```

Prints:

```
   A     B     C   
   a  b  a  b  a  b
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_table` after resetting your index:

```py
import pandas as pd

kdict = {'A': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 'B': {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, 'C': {'a': 5, 'b': 6}}

df5 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(kdict, orient='index').stack()
print(df5.reset_index().pivot_table(columns=['level_0', 'level_1']))
```

Output:

```
level_0  A     B     C   
level_1  a  b  a  b  a  b
0        1  2  3  4  5  6
```